# Android Service Creating new Instance of Singleton Class

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-service

I am using A Singleton Class for holding some data through out of application Which is some Queue.

I am creating Singleton Class Instance `onCreate` method of my `Application` Class.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Queue.getInstance(); // this is my singleton class instance
  }
```

After this I am adding data inside of this singleton class in my activities

```
Queue.getInstance().addItem(qItem);
Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Added Item Queue Size: "+Queue.getInstance().getQueueList().size());
```

Until this Everything working fine. I can access data in my `Activities` and `ListView Adapter` however When I Start Service and try to access data `onCreate` of service

```
Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Playing Item Queue Size: "+Queue.getInstance().getQueueList().size()+" Current Item No. "+Queue.getInstance().getCurrentPlayingItem());
String url = Queue.getInstance().getQueueItem(Queue.getInstance().getCurrentPlayingItem()).getLinkUrl();
```

My Singleton Instance become null and my singleton creates new instance. Which cause my data loss inside of Service.

Following is flow of my error.

1. On Start of Application Create Instance - Working
2. Add data from Activities and Adapters - Working
3. Start Service and Access Data - **Not Working because Singleton
   Instance become null inside service**

Following is the code of my Singleton Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.taazi.utils.Constants;

import android.util.Log;

public class Queue {
    private ArrayList<QueueItem> mQueueList;
    static Queue mInstance;
    private int currentPlayingItem=0;

    private Queue(){
        mQueueList = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();
    }

    public static Queue getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new Queue();
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "New Instance");
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void addItem(QueueItem item){
        mQueueList.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position){
        mQueueList.remove(position);
    }

    public ArrayList<QueueItem> getQueueList(){
        return mQueueList;
    }

    public QueueItem getQueueItem(int position){
        return mQueueList.get(position);
    }

    public int getCurrentPlayingItem() {
        return currentPlayingItem;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayingItem(int currentPlayingItem) {
        this.currentPlayingItem = currentPlayingItem;
    }


}
```

AudioPlayBackService.Java

```
package com.taazi.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.taazi.helper.NotificationHelperNew;
import com.taazi.models.Queue;
import com.taazi.models.QueueItem;
import com.taazi.utils.Constants;

public class AudioPlayBackService extends Service {

    /**
     * Called to go toggle between pausing and playing the music
     */
    public static final String TOGGLEPAUSE_ACTION = "com.taazi.services.togglepause";

    /**
     * Called to go to pause the playback
     */
    public static final String PAUSE_ACTION = "com.taazi.services.pause";

    /**
     * Called to go to stop the playback
     */
    public static final String STOP_ACTION = "com.taazi.services.stop";

    /**
     * Called to go to the previous track
     */
    public static final String PREVIOUS_ACTION = "com.taazi.services.previous";

    /**
     * Called to go to the next track
     */
    public static final String NEXT_ACTION = "com.taazi.services.next";

    /**
     * Used to build the notification
     */
    private NotificationHelperNew mNotificationHelper;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
     // Initialize the notification helper
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelperNew(this);

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Playing Item Queue Size: "+Queue.getInstance().getQueueList().size()+" Current Item No. "+Queue.getInstance().getCurrentPlayingItem());
        String url = Queue.getInstance().getQueueItem(Queue.getInstance().getCurrentPlayingItem()).getLinkUrl();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(url));
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        updateNotification();
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mNotificationHelper.killNotification();
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }

    /**
     * Updates the notification, considering the current play and activity state
     */
    private void updateNotification() {
        QueueItem item =  Queue.getInstance().getQueueItem(Queue.getInstance().getCurrentPlayingItem());
            mNotificationHelper.buildNotification("", item.getArtist(),
                    item.getTitle(), (long)50, null, true);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.taazi.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />


    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="com.taazi.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.taazi.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Music service -->
        <service
            android:name="com.taazi.services.AudioPlayBackService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:process=":main" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you running the service in a separate process?. Running it in a separate process will lead to this (breaking of Singleton pattern)

Comment: include your manifest for Service too

Comment: Add code of your service onCreate() method and manifest file.

Comment: @waqaslam More code added.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am using `startService(playBackServiceIntent);` for Starting service.

Comment: Use application context while creating singleton class instance. Also use same context while creating service. So while sharing same context there will not be issue. This will not reset the Singleton Class instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running your `Service` in a different process which is not the same as your `Application` context, that's why the Queue turns out to by **null** in the new process.

Remove the following from your `Service` in manifest and you are good to go:

```
android:process=":main"
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to make use of `HandlerThread` in your service to offload some heavy operations.

Comment: Just also note that the `Queue` implementation as it stands is not thread safe.

Comment: @Floris Please can you share some safe implementation Example? I need a Queue available throughout the application.

Comment: @AhmedNawaz You may use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to make your list thread-safe. Or use `Handler` and its messaging queue to add/remove items from your list.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a bash, but in the mean time you can use it as is, since thread-unsafe code only gives intermittent problems. Also read carefully the Oracle documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: @waqaslam let me learn about these two. I will try this. Because running service on same process causing hang in my app.

Comment: If you require service to work in a different process, but also want to control it, then you may make use of `BroadcastListener` in your scenario too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the thread-safe version.

```
    // package, imports ...

    public class Queue {

        // Make 100% sure your QueueItem class is immutable! Otherwise it will not be thread safe!
        // Also, it makes more sense (more readable) to put your QueueItem together with your Queue class 
        public static class QueueItem {
            //...
        }

        // changed the below line - was: private ArrayList<String> mQueueList; 
        // (search for programming against an interface rather than an implementation)
        private List<QueueItem> mQueueList; 
        static Queue mInstance;
        private int currentPlayingItem=0;

        private Queue() {
            // See javadoc on the synchronizedList() method. 
            mQueueList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<QueueItem>());
        }

        // Added synchronized keyword below 
        public synchronized static Queue getInstance(){
            if(mInstance == null){
                mInstance = new Queue();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "New Instance");
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        // Thread safe as it is (provided that QueueItem is immutable)
        public void addItem(QueueItem item){
            mQueueList.add(item);
        }

        // Thread safe as it is
        public void removeItem(int position){
            mQueueList.remove(position);
        }

        // This method is actually inherently flawed, remove this method - you should never need 
        // mQueueList - if you do need this method then your code is structured wrong.
        // changed the below line - was: public ArrayList<QueueItem> getQueueList(){
        /*public List<QueueItem> getQueueList(){
            return mQueueList;
        }*/

        // Thread safe as it is (provided that QueueItem is immutable) 
        public QueueItem getQueueItem(int position){
            return mQueueList.get(position);
        }

        // Made this method synchronized (and thus thread safe) - very unlikely to cause performance issue.
        public synchronized int getCurrentPlayingItem() {
            return currentPlayingItem;
        }

        // Made this method synchronized (and thus thread safe) - very unlikely to cause performance issue.
        public synchronized void setCurrentPlayingItem(int currentPlayingItem) {
            this.currentPlayingItem = currentPlayingItem;
        }


    }
```

Comment: On second thought, `removeItem(int position)` is not strictly thread-safe. Change the signature of the method to `removeItem(QueueItem item)` and change your implementation of the method to `mQueueList.remove(item);` to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Ooh Thanks. :)

I removed `getQueueList()` because It was needed for getting size. I made a new function `public int getQueueSize(){
  return mQueueList.size();
 }`

Comment: Okay. `removeItem(QueueItem item)` Doing this as well.

Comment: @Ahmed `getQueueSize()` is a much better idea! :)